# Simple Rest Controller returns 401 Unaothorized without security configuration

Tags: spring-boot

I've just created spring boot application and simple rest controller. It runs smoothly on default port 8080 but after adding configuration

```
server.port=9000
```

I'm getting 401 unauthorized. Why is that ? What am I missing ?

The only dependencies defined in my `build.gradle` is
`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'`

Comment: Kindly add more information about your question. Have you still trying to hit on port 8080 or 9000? Did you add any security dependency? if possible share github repo

Comment: For some reason my port was preoccupied (I guess). I debugged with `netstat -nlp`. It's all working now. 
`tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      68979/java`. Thanks for your response.